# How can a server broadcast a message to other clients?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

The program is intended to have multiple clients connect to a single server and the clients are able to send and receive messages among other clients.

For example if Client A says "Hi", Client B and Client C connected to the server would also receive "Hi".

In my current code, the server only receives the messages sent by the clients. 
I'm currently looking for a solution to have the server broadcast the message sent by a client (eg. ClientA) to other clients. Any advice would be much appreciated.

This server class handles the connections of multiple clients with the use of threads:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class EchoThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;

    //constructor
    public EchoThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        DataInputStream inp = null;

        try {
            inp = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

            //print whatever client is saying as long as it is not "Over"
            String line = "";
            while (!line.equals("Over")) {
                try {
                    line = inp.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(line);
                } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
            }

            //closes connection when client terminates the connection
            System.out.print("Closing Connection");
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }
}

public class Server {
    private static final int PORT = 5000;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        //starts the server
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Server started");
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...\n");
        } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }

        //while loop to accept multiple clients
        int count = 1;
        while(true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client " + count + " accepted!");
                count++;
            } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }

            //starts the server thread
            new EchoThread(socket).start();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the client class (I have multiple instances of this code running):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ClientA {
    private Socket socket = null;
    private DataInputStream input = null;
    private DataOutputStream output = null;

    public ClientA(String address, int port) {
        //establish connection
        try {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected");

            //takes input from terminal
            input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

            //sends output to the socket
            output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }

        //string to read message from input
        String line = "";

        //keep reading until "Over" is input
        while (!line.equals("Over")) {
            try {
                line = input.readLine();
                output.writeUTF(line);
            } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
        }
        //close the connection
        try {
            input.close();
            output.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        ClientA client = new ClientA("127.0.0.1", 5000);
    }
}
```

Do feel free to correct me on my code comments as I'm still not very familiar with socket programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did well. Just add a thread to receive message in ClientA; and store socket clients in Server.
In fact, Server is also a "client" when is send message to client.

I add some code based on your code. It works well, hope it's helpful.

```
class EchoThread extends Thread {
//*****What I add begin.
private static List<Socket> socketList = new ArrayList<>();
//*****What I add end.

private Socket socket;

//constructor
public EchoThread(Socket clientSocket) {
    this.socket = clientSocket;
    socketList.add(socket);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    DataInputStream inp = null;

    try {
        inp = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

        //print whatever client is saying as long as it is not "Over"
        String line = "";
        while (!line.equals("Over")) {
            try {
                line = inp.readUTF();
                System.out.println(line);

                //*****What I add begin.
                sendMessageToClients(line);
                //*****What I add end.
            } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); break;}
        }

        //closes connection when client terminates the connection
        System.out.print("Closing Connection");
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
}

//*****What I add begin.
private void sendMessageToClients(String line) throws IOException {
    for (Socket other : socketList) {
        if (other == socket) {
            continue;//ignore the sender client.
        }
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(other.getOutputStream());
        output.writeUTF(line);
    }
}
//*****What I add end.
```

}

```
public class ClientA {
private Socket socket = null;
private DataInputStream input = null;
private DataOutputStream output = null;

public ClientA(String address, int port) {
    //establish connection
    try {
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        //takes input from terminal
        input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        //sends output to the socket
        output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        //*****What I add begin.
        //Here create a thread to receive message from server.
        DataInputStream inp = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                String str;
                try {
                    str = inp.readUTF();
                    System.out.println(str);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();//error.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, "Client Reveiver.").start();
        //*****What I add end.

    } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }

    //string to read message from input
    String line = "";

    //keep reading until "Over" is input
    while (!line.equals("Over")) {
        try {
            line = input.readLine();
            output.writeUTF(line);
        } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }
    //close the connection
    try {
        input.close();
        output.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
}
```

Comment: To add, there are actually a lot of IO exceptions that need to be handled. Here is just a very simple example. :)

Comment: socketList should be a concurrent collection because clients may connect simultaneously. In this case I would suggest CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a single server thread which would maintain a register of the clients, possibly in a concurrent collection. Then I would send each message received from a client to all other clients.